# Проблема с практическим заданием после прочтения главы

Tags: python

[image: Это задние по практике которое я не могу выполнить]
Мой код не работает по какой-то причине, я перечитывал главу и не понял. Я просто начал думать, что это из-за того что книга по которой я учусь 2015г

Мой код:

```
age = 16
if age <= 18:
    print ("Ты совершенно летний")
else:
    print ("Ты ещё не подрос")
```

Comment: Python 3.9 судя по всему у меня

Comment: Чтобы правильно отправить код на этом сайте надо сделать пустую строку. В этой пустой строке ставишь ` ` ` без пробелов . После вводишь код нормально по строкам как в программе. После в пустой строке ставишь еще раз ` ` ` без пробелов. Сейчас гляну код чего там не так.

Comment: И еще, скинь какую ошибку тебе пишет.

Comment: О спасибо большое. У меня не ошибку выводило а один и тот же ответ. Я смог решить на своём примере. Но пример автора совсем другой теперь думаю прпавильно ли я сдела? и плюсы и минусы его кода и моего

Comment: ```
age = 18
if age >= 18:
    print ("Ты совершенно летний")
elif age < 18:
    print ("Ты ещё не подрос")
```
Это мой код

Comment: Нажми редактировать и отредактируй пост свой. Я сейчас тебе поправлю, попробуй потом зайти и посмотреть как это.

Comment: ```
age = 6
retirement = age - 65

if retirement < 10:
    print("Пора на пенсию, дружок!")
else:
    print("Дружище, тебе еще рано думать о пенсии!")
```
это код автора книги, который является ответом к этой задаче

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй подумать. Над твоим IF'ом. Просто чууууть чуть подумай. Ты ставишь знак МЕНЬШЕ и пишешь что он СОВЕРШЕННОЛЕТНИЙ. Точно МЕНЬШЕ? Не БОЛЬШЕ случаем?

Comment: Спасбо я заметил, просто не внимательный

Comment: Не думал что так быстро ответят. Очень приятно, что ты ответил :-)